# Text alignment issue in a quote banner

Tags: html, css

as you can see on [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hNf7x/) and on picture below, I'm struggling to get the signature placed as I want in my banner (I want it at the bottom right of the blue banner without interfering with the quote text alignment). The issue that I have is that with my current code the second line of the text is not perfectly aligned horizontally to the middle of the block (there's more space to the right than to the left).
How could I fix this and have full control on the signature position?
Many thanks,

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="block blueback center">
    <h2 class="white">dfjdsjdklj dsjfdslfjldsjf ldsjfdlsjflkdsfjdlskjf dljfdslfjkldsj dljfsdljfdklsj lkdjflkdsjdlks dsfjsdlkfjkls dsjflkdsfjdkl</h2><p class="signature">John Dupont</p>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {

    display: block;
        margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    clear: both;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h2 {
    color: #2165CB;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.white { color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline;

}

.center {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.signature {
display: inline;
margin-top: 20px; 
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
font-size: 12px;
color: #fff;
float: right;
font-weight: 700;
}
.blueback {
  background: #0064C4;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're interfering with each other because they're both set to be `inline` display. Floating the signature to the right starts on the same line as the quote. Thus the float ends up reducing the amount of width the quote perceives that it has, and a visually off-center center is the result.

I am not sure why `inline` is necessary. You could leave them both as `block` display and then align the quote's text to the right.

CSS:

```
.white {
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.signature {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle adjustment](http://jsfiddle.net/8nBAJ/1/)

If you compare it with yours, it looks visually the same (except the quote text is now centered).

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative margins:

```
.signature{
    margin-right: -20px;
}
```

But I would move the `padding` from the outer `div` to be `margins` of inner `h2` and used `margin-left` on class `signature`:

```
.block {
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    clear: both;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h2 {
    color: #2165CB;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.signature{
    margin-left: <put here>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to define `float: left;` for your `white` class as you have defined `float: right;` for your `.signature` and other things you can manage such as margins and paddings.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hNf7x/1/)